# Substring with dynamic length

Tags: c#, string

I need to get value of below string into 2 variables.

Input

> 6.3-full-day-care

Expected output:

```
var price=6.3; //The input is dynamic.Cannot get fixed length
var serviceKey="full-day-care";
```

How can I do that? `Substring` doesn't help here.

Comment: Have u tried String.Split?

Comment: What is the pattern here? Is it first `-` char?

Comment: How can `Substring` doesn't help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "6.3-full-day-care";
int index = s.IndexOf('-'); //This gets index of first '-' character

var price = s.Substring(0, index);
var serviceKey = s.Substring(index + 1);

Console.WriteLine(price);
Console.WriteLine(serviceKey);
```

Output will be;

```
6.3
full-day-care
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/bUa30R)</kbd>.

Comment: @Sampath I commanly use [`Ideone`](http://ideone.com/) which support a lot of programming languages. Just take a look.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like:

```
var val = "6.3-full-day-care"; 
var index = val.IndexOf("-"); //first occuarance of -

var price =double.Parse(val[index]); 
var serviceKey = val.Substring(index);
```

Just to give idea. It's beter naturally use `double.TryParse(..)` on `price`

```
double price = 0; 
double.TryParse(val[index], out prince, System.Globalization.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: better*. Also, the `= 0` is redundant since it's an `out` parameter to `TryParse` (also misspelled as `prince` in the second instruction)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var s = "6.3-full-day-care";
var index = s.IndexOf('-');
var price = s.Substring(0, index);
var serviceKey = s.Substring(index + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the price and the key are always separated with a '-':

```
string s = "6.3-full-day-care";
int separatorIdx = s.IndexOf( '-' ); // get idx of first '-'

// split original string
string price = s.Substring( 0, separatorIdx );
string serviceKey = s.Substring( separatorIdx+1, s.Length );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String.Split with a maximum count http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

```
string s = "6.3-full-day-care";
string[] parts = s.split(new char[]{'-'}, 1);

var price = parts[0];
var serviceKey = parts[1];
```